# currency converter! (If statements)

Tags: javascript

Im quite new at Javascript however I have been trying to create a currency converter using html select which is working great, however when calling the function it seems to skip straight over the if statements straight onto the else { } statement

```
function convUSD()
{
    RATE_GBP = 0.632111252;
    RATE_EURO = 0.746435769;
    RATE_AUD = 0.92945441;

    if(document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0 &&  document.frmCurrencyC.radioUSD.checked)
    {
        window.alert("Sorry cant do USD to USD convertion! Please select another value.");
    }
    else if(document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0 &&  document.frmCurrencyC.radioGBP.checked)
    {
        inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
        outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_GBP;
        document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
    }
    else if(document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0 &&  document.frmCurrencyC.radioEURO.checked)
    {
        inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
        outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_EURO;
        document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
    }
    else if(document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0 &&  document.frmCurrencyC.radioAUD.checked)
    {
        inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
        outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_AUD;
        document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("Whoops there was an error");
    }
}
```

The first If statement works fine however when I actually want to do for example USD to GBP it heads straight to the else statement.

If you guys spot any errors or just well anything it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the HTML form this code references. If you can, post it all to http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X8MyF/ Is the full html/js code , thanks

Comment: Almost all of that code is redundant. first, check `selectedIndex`.  If non-zero then exit.  Next, figure out the conversion rate by which checkbox is checked.  Now parse the text, multiply by conversion rate, and spit it back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your logic mixed up:

First you check to see which currency you are converting to by looking at which radio was selected:

```
function calculateCC() {
    if (document.frmCurrencyC.radioUSD.checked) {
        convUSD();
    }
    // etc
}
```

Then I would expect you would look at the drop down list to see what currency you are converting from, but instead, you check the radios, enforcing that the drop down list selection matches the "to" currency:

```
function convUSD() {
    ...
    if (document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0 &&
        document.frmCurrencyC.radioGBP.checked) {
        ...
    }
    // etc
}
```

Looking at your code, it seems that in your first function, you need to be checking for the "from" currency, not the "to" currency.  So, in `calculateCC()`, look at the drop down list, instead of the radio buttons:

```
function calculateCC() {
    if (document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0) {
        convUSD();
    }
    // etc
}
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/X8MyF/2/

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you can simplify this a lot by reducing the if's. It will be quicker to run and ultimately easier to debug.
This code should help you identify your bug more readily too, although without seeing the rest of  your code and the HTML, I can't see a good reason why your original code is failing.  You could try setting us up a test site at jsfiddle.net and sharing the link; that lets us test and debug your code in its entirety.

```
function convUSD()
{
    RATE_GBP = 0.632111252;
    RATE_EURO = 0.746435769;
    RATE_AUD = 0.92945441;

    if (document.selectBox.slBoxCurrency.selectedIndex == 0)
    {
        if (document.frmCurrencyC.radioUSD.checked) {
            window.alert("Sorry cant do USD to USD convertion! Please select another value.");
        }
        else if (document.frmCurrencyC.radioGBP.checked) {
            inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
            outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_GBP;
            document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
        }
        else if (document.frmCurrencyC.radioEURO.checked){
            inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
            outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_EURO;
            document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
        }
        else if (document.frmCurrencyC.radioAUD.checked) {
            inputBox = parseFloat(document.frmCurrencyC.textInputNum.value);
            outPutBox = inputBox * RATE_AUD;
            document.frmCurrencyC.textOutPutTotal.value = outPutBox;
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Whoops there was an error");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("selected index != 0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see you've already posted a fiddle, still the change I've identified here may help.

Comment: I do apologize for the standard of coding , looking through tutorials and going on instinct is the way I've been going! I have noted how you simplified the If' statements for the future Russ C ! Unfortunately I still can't figure out why its still skipping out the rest of the statements : /

Comment: Nothing to apologize for; just trying to offer a bit of guidance that will make your life easier!